# upload a file to s3 php script

Tags: php, amazon-s3, file-upload

I'm trying to upload a file to s3 with php. I copied this code from GitHub, and after subbing in my credentials it seems to work fine. However there's one part in it that frankly I don't understand and seems to be written wrong.

They use two `try` statements and three `catch` blocks. Also they're named differently: one uses `S3Exception`, and the other uses just `Exception`. From what I understand `S3Exception` is correct and you should not have more catches than you do tries.  Am I correct in my assumption?

Heres the link to the GitHub: [link](https://gist.github.com/keithweaver/70eb06d98b008113ce97f6148fbea83d#file-s3-upload-via-form-php-L66-70)

```
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
        die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error:' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple catch blocks to do different things for different types of exceptions. In your case above, the first block will only catch S3Exceptions. The second block will catch all other types of exceptions.